# Kotlin data class with different backing field type

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a simple class used for JSON serialization. For this purpose, the external interface uses `String`s, but the internal representation is different.

```java
public class TheClass {

    private final ComplexInfo info;

    public TheClass(String info) {
        this.info = new ComplexInfo(info);
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info.getAsString();
    }

    // ...more stuff which uses the ComplexInfo...
}
```

I have this working in Kotlin (not sure if there's a better way). But the non-val/var constructor prevents me from using `data`.

```
/*data*/ class TheClass(info: String) {

    private val _info = ComplexInfo(info)

    val info: String
        get() = _info.getAsString()


    // ...more stuff which uses the ComplexInfo...
}
```

How do I get this working as a `data class`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of a private `ComplexInfo` property declared in the primary constructor and a [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) that accepts a `String`.

Optionally, make the primary constructor private.

Example:

```
data class TheClass private constructor(private val complexInfo: ComplexInfo) {

    constructor(infoString: String) : this(ComplexInfo(infoString))

    val info: String get() = complexInfo.getAsString()
}
```

Note that it's the `complexInfo` property that is used in the data class generated members implementations.

Comment: I do get a warning: "private data class constructor is exposed via the 'generated' copy method".

Comment: Basically, the warning means that, while usually you want a private constructor to restrict its calls and have the control over where it's called, here, the constructor is also implicitly called in the generated `copy` implementation. You can make the constructor non-private (`protected constructor` will go, though it may look meaningless) or suppress the warning with `@Suppress("DataClassPrivateConstructor")` (that's what IntelliJ suppress quick fix inserts).

Comment: Yeah the class will be closed by default anyway. Thanks again for the solution.